# How to set the seed for Math.random() in Apex

Tags: apex-code

Is there a way to set the seed for the random number generator in Apex? And if so; which function do I use for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It likely isn't possible to seed the RNG in Apex.  If you need a repeatable sequence of random numbers, you'll have to implement a seeded pseudo random number generator yourself.

On the Apex platform, I'm sure they have a huge source of entropy available to generate random numbers, and there's no need for you to seed the generator.

Comment: Do you have any hints on how to implement a random number generator?

Comment: You should probably explain why `Math.random()` isn't sufficient for your needs.  Wikipedia has a decent article on [pseudo random number generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) you could look at.

Comment: It's what you said; I need a repeatable sequence of random numbers. Thanks for the link, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to seed the built-in random number generator in Salesforce.  I was in the same boat as you.  I wanted to be able to use a seed, so that I could create repeatable random numbers.

So, I thought I'd attempt to write my own RNG. I spent a number of days scouring the Internet for algorithms.  I was able to piece together a pretty comprehensive library of functions borrowing from various sources.  The classes are: "Random.cls", which is the main RNG class, and "Random_Test.cls", which is the test code.

It has the following methods:

1. nextInteger(upperLimit)
2. nextLong(upperLimit)
3. nextDouble(upperLimit)
4. nextUniform() - Same function as Math.Random() to return a Double between 0.0 and 1.0.
5. nextIntegerInRange(lowerLimit, upperLimit)
6. nextLongInRange(lowerLimit, upperLimit)
7. nextDoubleInRange(lowerLimit, upperLimit)
8. shuffle(List<Object>) - destroys the order of the original list
9. shuffleWithCopy(List<Object>) - return a shuffled copy of the list, in case you wish to preserve the list's original order (less efficient than "shuffle(List<Object>)")

The "Random.cls" documents the sources that I borrowed from in case you want to read more about random number generators.

I put the code out on GitHub for anyone who wants it: https://github.com/DeviousBard/Salesforce/tree/master